# BeautifulSoup XML Python extracting attributes from specific tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

This XML document contains the set of tags `events-data`. I want to extract information from the most RECENT `events-data`. For example, in the code below I want to go to the *last* `events-data` tag, go down to the `event-date` tag and extract the text of the `date` child tag. At the moment I am using BeautifulSoup in Python to traverse this document. Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <first-tag>
          <second-tag>
            <events-data>
               <event-date>
                    <date>20040913</date>
               </event-date>
            </events-data>

          <events-data> #the one i want to traverse to grab date text
             <event-date>
               <date>20040913</date>
             </event-date>
          </events-data> 
         </second-tag>
       </first-tag>
```

Comment: I was thinking, as in `elementtree` or `minidom` where you can traverse the tags based on index and length,  but I cannot think of a syntax (or find one for that matter) that would work for BeautifulSoup. Keep in mind I am still new to beautifulsoup.

Comment: Somehow it has to count the number of times `events-data` occurs, maybe by `numEvents = len(soup.find('events-data'))` and then read child tags at that index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using BeautifulSoup 3

```
import os
import sys

# Import Custom libraries
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

xml_str = \
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <first-tag>
      <second-tag>
        <events-data>
           <event-date>
                <date>20040913</date>
           </event-date>
        </events-data>

      <events-data>
         <event-date>
           <date>20040913</date>
         </event-date>
      </events-data> 
     </second-tag>
   </first-tag>
'''
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)

event_data_location = lambda x: x.name == "events-data"

events = soup.findAll(event_data_location)
if(events):
    # The last event-data
    print events[-1].text
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks! But one more request, say there were more tags within `event-date`, how would one grab those? i feel like its something along the lines of `print events[-1].text(..another tag..)`

Comment: Oh nevermind i'll just use this for each child tag. +1 great fast work thanks bud!